# edit phpMyAdmin in a script

Tags: bash, sed

I need to change phpMyAdmin.conf in a shell script

all 127.0.0.1 ip's need to be changed in my host ip

my idea:

> sed -i ' s /127.0.0.1 /192.168.33.22 /g "
>   /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf

but this wouldn't work, any idea's?

Comment: Why didn't that work? What was the result/the error you saw instead?

Answer (score 0):

The command as written is not correct:

> ```
> sed -i ' s /127.0.0.1 /192.168.33.22 /g " /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
> ```

Perhaps you pasted it incorrectly. This should work:

```
sed -i 's/127.0.0.1/192.168.33.22/g' /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
```